# IllegalStateException when unmarshalling from child node with XMLEventReader

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm working with some .xml and stumbled in a *never seen before* exception. Here is the broken code:

```
public class UnmarshallProva {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JAXBContext jaxbCx;
    Unmarshaller mavByXml;
    FileReader fr;
    XMLInputFactory xif;
    XMLEventReader xer;
    int mavv = 0;
    try {
        jaxbCx = JAXBContext.newInstance(MavType.class);
        mavByXml = jaxbCx.createUnmarshaller();
        fr = new FileReader(new File(args[0]));
        xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        xer = xif.createXMLEventReader(fr);

        while(xer.hasNext()) {
            XMLEvent xe = xer.nextEvent();
            if(xe.isStartElement()) {
                if(xe.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("mav")) {
                    if(xer.peek() != null) {
                        mavByXml.unmarshal(xer, MavType.class).getValue();
                    }
                    mavv++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(UnmarshallProva.class.getName()+" DONE. "+mavv+" MAv.");

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The class `MavType` is generated by `xjc` command. As the `XMLEventReader` find the first `<mav>` tag, it try to unmarshall and return this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: reader must be on a START_ELEMENT event, not a 4 event
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:449)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:430)
at prove.UnmarshallProva.main(UnmarshallProva.java:38)
```

Still puzzling why is this not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Cause

`XMLEventReader` doesn't have a method to get the current event, so when you pass it to the `Unmarshaller` it is going to ask for the next event (it can't get the `XMLEvent` that you already asked for with `xer.nextEvent()`).

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html

### What You Could Do

You could change your `while` logic to do the following:

```
    while(xer.hasNext()) {
        XMLEvent xe = xer.peek(); // CHANGE
        if(xe.isStartElement()) {
            if(xe.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("mav")) {
                // if(xer.peek() != null) {
                    mavByXml.unmarshal(xer, MavType.class).getValue();
                // }
                mavv++;
            }
        }
        // NEW
        if(xer.hasNext()) {
           xer.nextTag();
        }
    }
```

### What I Would Do Instead

I would recommend using `XMLStreamReader` instead to get the behaviour you are looking for.  I have a complete example on my blog that you may find useful:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html